# wcf warnings and error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to debug why my WCF service seems to randomly hang under high load.  I added some trace and got the warings and errors below:

```
warning: PipeConnetion aborted
warning: Failed to open System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel
warning: Faulted System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel
warning: An incoming channel was disposed because there was an error while attempting to open it.
error: System.IO.PipeException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
There was an error writing to the pipe: The pipe is being closed. (232, 0xe8).
```

the stacktrace for the error is:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.WriteHelper(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,         Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout, Object&amp; holder)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32   size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump()
System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

I cannot find any information related to these errors.  Anybody have an idea or some pointers as to where I should start looking?

edit:  This service is hosted within a Windows service, and is a InstanceContextMode.Single.  The client making these calls creates and disposes of the proxy after each call.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the `ReceiveTimeout` in the BindingConfiguration for the Service in `Web.Config`.

```
receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
```

Maximum is `receiveTimeout="infinite"` but I certainly don't recommend that ;)

You could also try changing the `InstanceContextMode` to `PerCall` in the `ServiceBehavior` Decoration in the class where you have defined your Service.

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall
```